# Having images centred in columns

Tags: android

I have three ToggleButton elements, each of which is a 50x70px image. I want these images centred in columns across the page (i.e. there are three columns, each of which takes up 1/3rd of the page's width, and each of which has an image centred horizontally inside it), but if I use a LinearLayout or TableLayout the images get stretched to become 33% of the page's width each. What should I be doing?

```
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTable" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_people" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person1Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:background="@drawable/person1_button" android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person2Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:background="@drawable/person2_button" android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person3Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:background="@drawable/person3_button" android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: explain what you mean by the last part of your statement.

Comment: The last part of the statement being "what should I be doing"? What I mean is, what layout properties should I be using to get three images evenly spaced across the page without them being stretched to completely fill the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buttons are scaled to 1/3 of the screen just because `android:layout_weight="1"` has higher priority than `android:layout_width="51px"`. To avoid this you can try to include each `ToggleButton` to its own `LinearLayout`. Like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTable" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_people" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person1Button"
            android:layout_width="51px" 
            android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person2Button"
            android:layout_width="51px" 
            android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person3Button"
            android:layout_width="51px"
            android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I hadn't thought of doing it that way. Do you know why Android overrides width and height for TableLayout elements?

Comment: it because it has to scale all elemnts the same in terms of height and width so that they evenly distribute, because its assumed data in a table is uniform.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that GrAnd, but its the best way to do do it. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks you two, you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This layout code worked for me... (**Note**: this is your code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person1Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person2Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/person3Button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="51px" android:layout_height="68px"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""></ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

It shows 3 toggle buttons at the top and shows them evenly spaced at the top which each took up 1/3 of the screen.

This most likely means that the scale of this layout is not related to why its streching.

Comment: Hhm, that still doesn't work for me: the difference between your code and mine seems to be that you've removed the "weight" from the LinearLayout tag, and replaced it with a gravity="center_horizontal". This still results in the three images being stretched to 1/3rd of the screen each, as opposed to 51px each.

Comment: You are right, well if you want to fix that then just change layout_width to wrap_content

Comment: Ahhh ok. Thanks! I thought I'd tried every combination of stuff, but I guess I hadn't tried that one.